# Which one is the best method for Full text search ie via NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE, BOOLEAN MODE or QUERY EXPANSION

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM posts
  WHERE MATCH (title)
  AGAINST ('MySQL'  in boolean mode );

SELECT * FROM posts
  WHERE MATCH (title)
  AGAINST ('MySQL'   );

SELECT * FROM posts
  WHERE MATCH (title)
  AGAINST ('MySQL'  with query expansion );
```

I executed all three methods, but all return different results. What is the best method for usage?

Comment: Which one fits your needs?

Comment: Be cautious when asking for the "best" way to do something on SO as it's prone to opinion based answers. What are your requirements?